# Prove that there isn't such a function, which would be continuous at each rational point and discontinuous in each irrational point.

Tags: real-analysis

Prove that there isn't such a function, which would be continuous at each rational point and discontinuous in each irrational point.

---

I find this question very challenging and have no idea even how to start off with the proof. Please suggest a proof or any hint.